# Rundeck Community Version SSO with Google Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, rundeck, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

Has anyone successfully enabled SSO with Rundeck Community version and Google accounts? From what I'm reading full SSO is only supported in the Enterprise version. In theory, you can configure the community version with pre-auth and it should work, but I'm having trouble making this work with Google IAP.

Thanks!

Comment: Using oauth2-proxy + nginx could be possible: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5656#issuecomment-621059856 (here the Google side doc: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've gotten this method to work on another application where I needed SSO with a 3rd party OIDC. But in the case of IAP, shouldn't I be able to get it to work without the oauth2-proxy since the authentication step is already being done with the out of the box IAP login? I was hoping to somehow have rundeck use the IAP creds for pre-auth without having to implement oath2-proxy